# mixed model vs. markov chain

Tags: probability, model, mixed-model

I have a longitudinal data with multiple time points (measured twice every year). There was seasonal difference on the outcome variable of interest (BMIz) if using mixed model (where time points were nested within kids, and kids were nested within schools).

I also calculated the percentages of children transitioning between weight categories from assessment to assessment. In that graph, there were clear seasonal differences in the transition percentages. However, if I use 1st order Markov Chain transitional model and with the meaningful categorized outcome variable (healthy weight,  overweight, and obese), there was no seasonal difference on the transition probability matrices. Is Markov Chain use some smoothing function, so the seasonal differences get smoothed out?

Does anyone could provide some explanations? I appreciate any inputs.

Thanks!